# Noether normalisation morphism with specified images of finitely many points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a finitely generated $K$-algebra, and $X$ the affine scheme corresponding to $A$. Then Noether normalisation says that there exists a finite surjective morphism $X \to \mathbb A^d$. But, say we are given finitely many points $x_1, \ldots, x_r \in X$. Can we find a finite surjective morphism $\pi \colon X \to \mathbb A^d$ such that $\pi(x_i)=0$ for all $i=1, \ldots, r$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will always come down to the case $X = \mathbb A^d$ (but $\pi$ might not be an isomorphism) since you can just compose an arbitrary map $X \to \mathbb A^d$ with an endomorphism of $\mathbb A^d$. And the special case is going to depend on how big $r$ is relative to $d$, and the geometry of the point configuration (i.e. how general the points are).

Comment: Here are some (potentially annoying) questions about the setup that affect how the answer is written: do you make any assumptions about $K$, like being algebraically closed? Do you also assume that the $x_i$ are closed points?

Comment: I do not make any assumptions on $K$. We may assume that the $x_i$ are closed, since that is the case I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can always do this in the case that $x_i$ are closed points, and as Tabes Bridges points out in the comments, it is enough to solve the problem for $\Bbb A^n$. In fact, by induction, it suffices to prove the claim for two points in $\Bbb A^n$.

Suppose we have two points $a_1,a_2\in\Bbb A^n$. Then for each $i$, let $p_i(x_i)$ be a monic polynomial in $x_i$ vanishing on the $i^{th}$ coordinate of both $a_1$ and $a_2$. The map $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto (p_1(x_1),\cdots,p_n(x_n))$ induced by $k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]\to k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, $y_i\mapsto p_i(x_i)$ is finite (the monomials $\prod x_i^{c_i}$ where $0\leq c_i<\deg p_i$ form a basis for $k[x]$ as a $k[y]$-algebra) and sends the two points to zero. It's also clear to see that this map is surjective, so we're done.

Comment: This is certainly very helpful, thank you! But I think this only proves the claim for closed points $p=(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ that correspond to maximal ideals of the type $(x_1 - p_1, \ldots, x_n-p_n)$. If $k$ is not algebraically closed, then not all maximal ideals in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ are of this type, right? Furthermore - and I may be blind here - but I don't see why your map is surjective, unless we again assume $k$ to be algebraically closed. Could you elaborate on that? Maybe the way to go is to show that ring map $k[y_1, \ldots, y_n] \to k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is injective.

Comment: @LayerCake This proof works over any field for any closed points. When I say "coordinate", I'm thinking of the closed points of $\Bbb A^n_k$ as points of $\overline{k}^n$ up to the Galois action - one way to rephrase the choice of $p_i(x_i)$ would be to say "pick $p_i(x_i)$ to be a nonzero element in $k[x_i]\cap m_{p_1}\cap m_{p_2}$", where the $m$s are maximal ideals. This should make that portion clearer.

Comment: I don't see your issue with surjectivity, unless maybe you're getting thrown off by thinking about $k$-points? Remember that a finite map like we have here is closed, so it's image is closed. But this image isn't contained in any proper subvariety, for exactly the reason you note: the map on coordinate algebras is injective. So that means it must be surjective.

Comment: Ah yes, now everything is clear. Brilliant!